# How do I retrieve mean value for each height level?

Tags: python, numpy

For each height level in the data, I need to print the mean value of this height data. The data is listed here:

```
array([[[[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     ..., 
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]],

    [[   34.21287537,    34.20989609,    34.21205139, ...,
         34.20757675,    34.21348953,    34.21245956],
     [   34.21684265,    34.21436691,    34.21203613, ...,
         34.19748688,    34.20864487,    34.2153244 ],
     [   34.21459198,    34.21549606,    34.20995331, ...,
         34.18675232,    34.19908905,    34.21184921],
     ..., 
     [   34.21892548,    34.22324753,    34.22005844, ...,
         34.1985321 ,    34.20095444,    34.20874405],
     [   34.20901489,    34.21518326,    34.22049713, ...,
         34.20082855,    34.19775772,    34.20313644],
     [   34.20801163,    34.20925903,    34.21076584, ...,
         34.20703888,    34.20729065,    34.20755386]],

    [[   68.50743866,    68.50121307,    68.50645447, ...,
         68.50447845,    68.51256561,    68.50937653],
     [   68.51385498,    68.50878143,    68.50476074, ...,
         68.4848175 ,    68.50759125,    68.516716  ],
     [   68.51290894,    68.50955963,    68.49982452, ...,
         68.46362305,    68.48851013,    68.51026917],
     ..., 
     [   68.52046204,    68.52880859,    68.52523804, ...,
         68.47465515,    68.48323059,    68.49970245],
     [   68.49790192,    68.51045227,    68.51911926, ...,
         68.48313904,    68.47921753,    68.48879242],
     [   68.49653625,    68.49960327,    68.50336456, ...,
         68.50052643,    68.50041199,    68.49834442]],

    ..., 
    [[ 3937.5559082 ,  3937.34326172,  3937.56713867, ...,
       3937.47753906,  3937.45922852,  3937.43481445],
     [ 3937.50830078,  3937.59033203,  3937.39282227, ...,
       3937.43701172,  3937.32348633,  3937.36889648],
     [ 3937.34692383,  3937.45556641,  3937.26049805, ...,
       3937.36401367,  3937.26098633,  3937.50170898],
     ..., 
     [ 3937.37158203,  3937.55834961,  3937.4230957 , ...,
       3937.44360352,  3937.55834961,  3937.31787109],
     [ 3937.36791992,  3937.36523438,  3937.51049805, ...,
       3937.44848633,  3937.35131836,  3937.33374023],
     [ 3937.42895508,  3937.4284668 ,  3937.37988281, ...,
       3937.37646484,  3937.48632812,  3937.53051758]],

    [[ 3987.22143555,  3987.00878906,  3987.23706055, ...,
       3987.13476562,  3987.1171875 ,  3987.09643555],
     [ 3987.17529297,  3987.26123047,  3987.06225586, ...,
       3987.09594727,  3986.98144531,  3987.03027344],
     [ 3987.01367188,  3987.12670898,  3986.92993164, ...,
       3987.02685547,  3986.92114258,  3987.16723633],
     ..., 
     [ 3987.03076172,  3987.2199707 ,  3987.08374023, ...,
       3987.10449219,  3987.21899414,  3986.97460938],
     [ 3987.02880859,  3987.02709961,  3987.17578125, ...,
       3987.10766602,  3987.00732422,  3986.99047852],
     [ 3987.09082031,  3987.09277344,  3987.04467773, ...,
       3987.03320312,  3987.14428711,  3987.19213867]],

    [[ 4037.14624023,  4036.93212891,  4037.16503906, ...,
       4037.05102539,  4037.03442383,  4037.01513672],
     [ 4037.1003418 ,  4037.19042969,  4036.98925781, ...,
       4037.01123047,  4036.89648438,  4036.94921875],
     [ 4036.93676758,  4037.0546875 ,  4036.85595703, ...,
       4036.94506836,  4036.83813477,  4037.08935547],
     ..., 
     [ 4036.94702148,  4037.13671875,  4036.99902344, ...,
       4037.02441406,  4037.13867188,  4036.88891602],
     [ 4036.94702148,  4036.94555664,  4037.09716797, ...,
       4037.02685547,  4036.92285156,  4036.90649414],
     [ 4037.01196289,  4037.015625  ,  4036.96655273, ...,
       4036.94995117,  4037.06176758,  4037.11157227]]],


   [[[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     ..., 
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]],

    [[   34.19182968,    34.19211578,    34.19773865, ...,
         34.20589828,    34.20449066,    34.1951561 ],
     [   34.19623184,    34.19226074,    34.19217682, ...,
         34.2063446 ,    34.20676422,    34.20332718],
     [   34.20330811,    34.20057678,    34.19517899, ...,
         34.19625092,    34.20174408,    34.2055397 ],
     ..., 
     [   34.19910049,    34.1975174 ,    34.18927383, ...,
         34.19667816,    34.19751358,    34.19699478],
     [   34.19695282,    34.20077515,    34.19703674, ...,
         34.20119858,    34.19481277,    34.19423676],
     [   34.19290543,    34.19966125,    34.20000458, ...,
         34.20391083,    34.19789124,    34.19244766]],

    [[   68.46511841,    68.46816254,    68.48286438, ...,
         68.4947052 ,    68.48622894,    68.46950531],
     [   68.4752655 ,    68.46940613,    68.47019196, ...,
         68.49662018,    68.4961853 ,    68.48711395],
     [   68.49156189,    68.48475647,    68.47511292, ...,
         68.47860718,    68.48865509,    68.49757385],
     ..., 
     [   68.48029327,    68.47402954,    68.45415497, ...,
         68.47582245,    68.47915649,    68.47854614],
     [   68.4797821 ,    68.48349762,    68.47532654, ...,
         68.48181915,    68.47315979,    68.47156525],
     [   68.47018433,    68.48558044,    68.48451233, ...,
         68.48760223,    68.47450256,    68.46736908]],

    ..., 
    [[ 3937.59619141,  3937.38208008,  3937.60546875, ...,
       3937.51098633,  3937.4934082 ,  3937.47192383],
     [ 3937.54370117,  3937.62890625,  3937.43066406, ...,
       3937.46411133,  3937.35400391,  3937.40039062],
     [ 3937.37988281,  3937.49194336,  3937.29760742, ...,
       3937.38867188,  3937.28198242,  3937.52563477],
     ..., 
     [ 3937.40185547,  3937.57714844,  3937.43920898, ...,
       3937.47363281,  3937.59106445,  3937.35009766],
     [ 3937.40356445,  3937.3972168 ,  3937.53857422, ...,
       3937.48583984,  3937.38549805,  3937.36791992],
     [ 3937.46826172,  3937.46728516,  3937.41381836, ...,
       3937.41772461,  3937.52441406,  3937.56762695]],

    [[ 3987.2421875 ,  3987.02709961,  3987.25537109, ...,
       3987.15209961,  3987.13500977,  3987.11450195],
     [ 3987.19213867,  3987.27880859,  3987.07885742, ...,
       3987.10791016,  3986.99609375,  3987.04516602],
     [ 3987.02880859,  3987.14257812,  3986.94628906, ...,
       3987.03662109,  3986.92993164,  3987.17797852],
     ..., 
     [ 3987.04833984,  3987.22949219,  3987.09082031, ...,
       3987.12426758,  3987.23950195,  3986.99365234],
     [ 3987.04785156,  3987.04272461,  3987.18920898, ...,
       3987.13037109,  3987.02758789,  3987.00976562],
     [ 3987.11206055,  3987.11230469,  3987.06103516, ...,
       3987.05664062,  3987.16577148,  3987.21118164]],

    [[ 4037.14624023,  4036.93212891,  4037.16503906, ...,
       4037.05102539,  4037.03442383,  4037.01513672],
     [ 4037.1003418 ,  4037.19042969,  4036.98925781, ...,
       4037.01123047,  4036.89648438,  4036.94921875],
     [ 4036.93676758,  4037.0546875 ,  4036.85595703, ...,
       4036.94506836,  4036.83813477,  4037.08935547],
     ..., 
     [ 4036.94702148,  4037.13671875,  4036.99902344, ...,
       4037.02441406,  4037.13867188,  4036.88891602],
     [ 4036.94702148,  4036.94555664,  4037.09716797, ...,
       4037.02685547,  4036.92285156,  4036.90649414],
     [ 4037.01196289,  4037.015625  ,  4036.96655273, ...,
       4036.94995117,  4037.06176758,  4037.11157227]]],


   [[[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     ..., 
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]],

    [[   34.20446777,    34.20052719,    34.19815826, ...,
         34.20582199,    34.20079422,    34.20202637],
     [   34.21053696,    34.20816422,    34.2024765 , ...,
         34.20986557,    34.21206284,    34.21391296],
     [   34.19842529,    34.19293976,    34.18836975, ...,
         34.20700836,    34.20596313,    34.20450592],
     ..., 
     [   34.14487076,    34.15826797,    34.17117691, ...,
         34.17651749,    34.16210175,    34.14500809],
     [   34.16115189,    34.16546631,    34.17008209, ...,
         34.18005753,    34.16591263,    34.15840912],
     [   34.18585968,    34.18474579,    34.18009186, ...,
         34.19102478,    34.18055725,    34.18193054]],

    [[   68.49851227,    68.48938751,    68.48140717, ...,
         68.50066376,    68.49211121,    68.49576569],
     [   68.50453949,    68.49729156,    68.48866272, ...,
         68.50941467,    68.51350403,    68.51328278],
     [   68.47364807,    68.46231079,    68.4575882 , ...,
         68.49608612,    68.49163055,    68.48778534],
     ..., 
     [   68.37734985,    68.40405273,    68.43086243, ...,
         68.435112  ,    68.40751648,    68.37718201],
     [   68.40971375,    68.41601562,    68.42681885, ...,
         68.44056702,    68.41567993,    68.4059906 ],
     [   68.46156311,    68.45780945,    68.44553375, ...,
         68.46590424,    68.44957733,    68.45439911]],

    ..., 
    [[ 3937.57666016,  3937.36474609,  3937.5847168 , ...,
       3937.49267578,  3937.47753906,  3937.45605469],
     [ 3937.52563477,  3937.60864258,  3937.40112305, ...,
       3937.45092773,  3937.33764648,  3937.38598633],
     [ 3937.36401367,  3937.47265625,  3937.27246094, ...,
       3937.38110352,  3937.27490234,  3937.51806641],
     ..., 
     [ 3937.4675293 ,  3937.62597656,  3937.47119141, ...,
       3937.47753906,  3937.6105957 ,  3937.40576172],
     [ 3937.42651367,  3937.41870117,  3937.56152344, ...,
       3937.47265625,  3937.3828125 ,  3937.3815918 ],
     [ 3937.453125  ,  3937.45751953,  3937.41650391, ...,
       3937.39501953,  3937.50854492,  3937.55444336]],

    [[ 3987.23193359,  3987.01953125,  3987.24609375, ...,
       3987.14355469,  3987.12719727,  3987.10644531],
     [ 3987.18334961,  3987.27001953,  3987.06494141, ...,
       3987.10253906,  3986.98803711,  3987.03833008],
     [ 3987.01928711,  3987.13305664,  3986.93359375, ...,
       3987.03344727,  3986.92675781,  3987.17333984],
     ..., 
     [ 3987.08105469,  3987.25537109,  3987.10839844, ...,
       3987.12402344,  3987.24731445,  3987.02050781],
     [ 3987.05981445,  3987.05419922,  3987.20288086, ...,
       3987.12182617,  3987.02514648,  3987.01611328],
     [ 3987.10449219,  3987.10839844,  3987.06420898, ...,
       3987.04418945,  3987.15698242,  3987.20385742]],

    [[ 4037.14624023,  4036.93212891,  4037.16503906, ...,
       4037.05102539,  4037.03442383,  4037.01513672],
     [ 4037.1003418 ,  4037.19042969,  4036.98925781, ...,
       4037.01123047,  4036.89648438,  4036.94921875],
     [ 4036.93676758,  4037.0546875 ,  4036.85595703, ...,
       4036.94506836,  4036.83813477,  4037.08935547],
     ..., 
     [ 4036.94702148,  4037.13671875,  4036.99902344, ...,
       4037.02441406,  4037.13867188,  4036.88891602],
     [ 4036.94702148,  4036.94555664,  4037.09716797, ...,
       4037.02685547,  4036.92285156,  4036.90649414],
     [ 4037.01196289,  4037.015625  ,  4036.96655273, ...,
       4036.94995117,  4037.06176758,  4037.11157227]]],


   [[[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     ..., 
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]],

    [[   34.2088623 ,    34.20285797,    34.20333481, ...,
         34.20357513,    34.20812225,    34.2084198 ],
     [   34.20095062,    34.19676971,    34.19678116, ...,
         34.20838928,    34.20900345,    34.20454407],
     [   34.18199158,    34.17631531,    34.18016434, ...,
         34.21203232,    34.20741272,    34.19777679],
     ..., 
     [   34.20244598,    34.20032501,    34.19802475, ...,
         34.20089722,    34.20354462,    34.20194244],
     [   34.20118332,    34.19509888,    34.19345093, ...,
         34.20210648,    34.20388412,    34.20378876],
     [   34.20446396,    34.19981766,    34.19599915, ...,
         34.20211029,    34.20681763,    34.20708084]],

    [[   68.49888611,    68.48752594,    68.49059296, ...,
         68.49337006,    68.49943542,    68.49966431],
     [   68.47949982,    68.47618866,    68.47901917, ...,
         68.50068665,    68.49752808,    68.48812103],
     [   68.43886566,    68.43549347,    68.447052  , ...,
         68.50945282,    68.48993683,    68.46613312],
     ..., 
     [   68.48223877,    68.48002625,    68.47723389, ...,
         68.48565674,    68.48921967,    68.48464966],
     [   68.47962189,    68.46920776,    68.46780396, ...,
         68.48887634,    68.49098969,    68.48608398],
     [   68.48958588,    68.47861481,    68.47537994, ...,
         68.48771667,    68.49675751,    68.496521  ]],

    ..., 
    [[ 3937.56103516,  3937.35009766,  3937.57592773, ...,
       3937.47436523,  3937.4597168 ,  3937.44165039],
     [ 3937.51806641,  3937.60327148,  3937.40551758, ...,
       3937.43896484,  3937.32373047,  3937.37524414],
     [ 3937.35839844,  3937.47192383,  3937.27734375, ...,
       3937.37719727,  3937.26806641,  3937.50732422],
     ..., 
     [ 3937.37646484,  3937.5534668 ,  3937.41503906, ...,
       3937.46118164,  3937.57080078,  3937.32788086],
     [ 3937.37548828,  3937.36694336,  3937.51293945, ...,
       3937.45874023,  3937.35839844,  3937.34008789],
     [ 3937.43457031,  3937.43261719,  3937.38354492, ...,
       3937.37988281,  3937.49023438,  3937.53564453]],

    [[ 3987.22021484,  3987.00805664,  3987.23779297, ...,
       3987.12841797,  3987.11206055,  3987.0949707 ],
     [ 3987.17602539,  3987.26416016,  3987.06542969, ...,
       3987.09179688,  3986.97583008,  3987.02905273],
     [ 3987.01513672,  3987.1315918 ,  3986.93481445, ...,
       3987.02905273,  3986.91967773,  3987.1652832 ],
     ..., 
     [ 3987.03027344,  3987.21313477,  3987.07495117, ...,
       3987.11108398,  3987.22314453,  3986.9777832 ],
     [ 3987.02880859,  3987.02392578,  3987.17333984, ...,
       3987.11035156,  3987.00805664,  3986.9909668 ],
     [ 3987.09082031,  3987.09082031,  3987.04223633, ...,
       3987.03149414,  3987.14257812,  3987.18994141]],

    [[ 4037.14624023,  4036.93212891,  4037.16503906, ...,
       4037.05102539,  4037.03442383,  4037.01513672],
     [ 4037.1003418 ,  4037.19042969,  4036.98925781, ...,
       4037.01123047,  4036.89648438,  4036.94921875],
     [ 4036.93676758,  4037.0546875 ,  4036.85595703, ...,
       4036.94506836,  4036.83813477,  4037.08935547],
     ..., 
     [ 4036.94702148,  4037.13671875,  4036.99902344, ...,
       4037.02441406,  4037.13867188,  4036.88891602],
     [ 4036.94702148,  4036.94555664,  4037.09716797, ...,
       4037.02685547,  4036.92285156,  4036.90649414],
     [ 4037.01196289,  4037.015625  ,  4036.96655273, ...,
       4036.94995117,  4037.06176758,  4037.11157227]]],


   [[[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     ..., 
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]],

    [[   34.2000351 ,    34.18941498,    34.18548965, ...,
         34.20226288,    34.20254898,    34.20256805],
     [   34.2033844 ,    34.20035553,    34.19132996, ...,
         34.20030975,    34.20077896,    34.20196152],
     [   34.20223236,    34.20491409,    34.20104218, ...,
         34.19875336,    34.20017242,    34.20199966],
     ..., 
     [   34.17694092,    34.17850876,    34.17822266, ...,
         34.18716812,    34.1852417 ,    34.18019867],
     [   34.1799736 ,    34.17520142,    34.1780014 , ...,
         34.19300079,    34.18999863,    34.18576813],
     [   34.1875267 ,    34.18222809,    34.17966461, ...,
         34.19828033,    34.19871521,    34.19506454]],

    [[   68.48371887,    68.4642868 ,    68.45394135, ...,
         68.48834229,    68.49024963,    68.49035645],
     [   68.49416351,    68.48825073,    68.46833038, ...,
         68.48651123,    68.48760223,    68.49149323],
     [   68.49206543,    68.49694824,    68.48986816, ...,
         68.48221588,    68.48532104,    68.49121857],
     ..., 
     [   68.43632507,    68.43695831,    68.43721008, ...,
         68.45930481,    68.45474243,    68.43965912],
     [   68.44087982,    68.43275452,    68.43909454, ...,
         68.47161865,    68.46368408,    68.45285034],
     [   68.45918274,    68.4458847 ,    68.44309235, ...,
         68.48279572,    68.48235321,    68.47303009]],

    ..., 
    [[ 3937.57397461,  3937.36328125,  3937.58740234, ...,
       3937.49389648,  3937.47436523,  3937.45166016],
     [ 3937.53320312,  3937.62133789,  3937.42700195, ...,
       3937.45043945,  3937.33862305,  3937.38867188],
     [ 3937.3815918 ,  3937.49780273,  3937.30859375, ...,
       3937.38964844,  3937.28369141,  3937.52758789],
     ..., 
     [ 3937.39819336,  3937.57592773,  3937.43530273, ...,
       3937.48876953,  3937.59301758,  3937.34741211],
     [ 3937.39624023,  3937.38232422,  3937.52246094, ...,
       3937.484375  ,  3937.37915039,  3937.36157227],
     [ 3937.45117188,  3937.44482422,  3937.38964844, ...,
       3937.39794922,  3937.5065918 ,  3937.5534668 ]],

    [[ 3987.23144531,  3987.01879883,  3987.24731445, ...,
       3987.14355469,  3987.12475586,  3987.10522461],
     [ 3987.18920898,  3987.27880859,  3987.08105469, ...,
       3987.10205078,  3986.98974609,  3987.04150391],
     [ 3987.03442383,  3987.15063477,  3986.95629883, ...,
       3987.0390625 ,  3986.93432617,  3987.18286133],
     ..., 
     [ 3987.04077148,  3987.22387695,  3987.08520508, ...,
       3987.12548828,  3987.23461914,  3986.98657227],
     [ 3987.04077148,  3987.03271484,  3987.17895508, ...,
       3987.12524414,  3987.02001953,  3987.00366211],
     [ 3987.10205078,  3987.1003418 ,  3987.04785156, ...,
       3987.04321289,  3987.15380859,  3987.20239258]],

    [[ 4037.14624023,  4036.93212891,  4037.16503906, ...,
       4037.05102539,  4037.03442383,  4037.01513672],
     [ 4037.1003418 ,  4037.19042969,  4036.98925781, ...,
       4037.01123047,  4036.89648438,  4036.94921875],
     [ 4036.93676758,  4037.0546875 ,  4036.85595703, ...,
       4036.94506836,  4036.83813477,  4037.08935547],
     ..., 
     [ 4036.94702148,  4037.13671875,  4036.99902344, ...,
       4037.02441406,  4037.13867188,  4036.88891602],
     [ 4036.94702148,  4036.94555664,  4037.09716797, ...,
       4037.02685547,  4036.92285156,  4036.90649414],
     [ 4037.01196289,  4037.015625  ,  4036.96655273, ...,
       4036.94995117,  4037.06176758,  4037.11157227]]],


   [[[    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     ..., 
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ],
     [    0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        , ...,
          0.        ,     0.        ,     0.        ]],

    [[   34.20126724,    34.1979332 ,    34.19779968, ...,
         34.19823837,    34.19875336,    34.19975281],
     [   34.20439911,    34.199646  ,    34.19061279, ...,
         34.20642853,    34.20412064,    34.20292664],
     [   34.20172119,    34.19914246,    34.19044113, ...,
         34.20433426,    34.20330811,    34.20406723],
     ..., 
     [   34.20079041,    34.20262527,    34.20119095, ...,
         34.19816589,    34.19902802,    34.19683075],
     [   34.20511246,    34.20733643,    34.20927429, ...,
         34.1936264 ,    34.19457626,    34.19810104],
     [   34.20048523,    34.20501328,    34.20562363, ...,
         34.19027328,    34.19144821,    34.19747543]],

    [[   68.48700714,    68.48094177,    68.47947693, ...,
         68.48243713,    68.48357391,    68.48529053],
     [   68.48946381,    68.4798584 ,    68.4631424 , ...,
         68.49642181,    68.4923172 ,    68.48878479],
     [   68.48499298,    68.47812653,    68.46133423, ...,
         68.49002075,    68.48813629,    68.4872818 ],
     ..., 
     [   68.49024963,    68.49320221,    68.4914856 , ...,
         68.4847641 ,    68.48635864,    68.48277283],
     [   68.49649811,    68.50474548,    68.50835419, ...,
         68.47048187,    68.47286987,    68.48214722],
     [   68.48762512,    68.496521  ,    68.50076294, ...,
         68.46537018,    68.46950531,    68.47885895]],

    ..., 
    [[ 3937.55786133,  3937.34887695,  3937.58178711, ...,
       3937.48754883,  3937.4597168 ,  3937.43530273],
     [ 3937.51367188,  3937.60009766,  3937.40551758, ...,
       3937.44799805,  3937.32983398,  3937.37231445],
     [ 3937.3581543 ,  3937.46630859,  3937.27294922, ...,
       3937.38598633,  3937.27612305,  3937.51171875],
     ..., 
     [ 3937.38037109,  3937.56347656,  3937.43408203, ...,
       3937.47265625,  3937.58496094,  3937.33447266],
     [ 3937.37841797,  3937.37451172,  3937.52612305, ...,
       3937.47070312,  3937.3684082 ,  3937.34619141],
     [ 3937.43408203,  3937.43652344,  3937.39550781, ...,
       3937.39501953,  3937.49707031,  3937.53686523]],

    [[ 3987.22241211,  3987.01171875,  3987.24487305, ...,
       3987.13989258,  3987.11645508,  3987.09521484],
     [ 3987.17700195,  3987.26611328,  3987.06811523, ...,
       3987.09960938,  3986.98291016,  3987.03027344],
     [ 3987.01733398,  3987.13037109,  3986.93481445, ...,
       3987.03588867,  3986.92675781,  3987.17016602],
     ..., 
     [ 3987.03637695,  3987.22314453,  3987.08959961, ...,
       3987.12158203,  3987.23510742,  3986.98461914],
     [ 3987.03442383,  3987.0324707 ,  3987.18457031, ...,
       3987.12084961,  3987.01733398,  3986.99731445],
     [ 3987.09399414,  3987.09716797,  3987.05395508, ...,
       3987.04394531,  3987.14990234,  3987.1953125 ]],

    [[ 4037.14624023,  4036.93212891,  4037.16503906, ...,
       4037.05102539,  4037.03442383,  4037.01513672],
     [ 4037.1003418 ,  4037.19042969,  4036.98925781, ...,
       4037.01123047,  4036.89648438,  4036.94921875],
     [ 4036.93676758,  4037.0546875 ,  4036.85595703, ...,
       4036.94506836,  4036.83813477,  4037.08935547],
     ..., 
     [ 4036.94702148,  4037.13671875,  4036.99902344, ...,
       4037.02441406,  4037.13867188,  4036.88891602],
     [ 4036.94702148,  4036.94555664,  4037.09716797, ...,
       4037.02685547,  4036.92285156,  4036.90649414],
     [ 4037.01196289,  4037.015625  ,  4036.96655273, ...,
       4036.94995117,  4037.06176758,  4037.11157227]]]])
```

The height gets measured 6 times where height data is obtained. Each time, there are 99 levels of height data being taken, so there are 99 heights that are measured, and the 99 heights are measured 6 times. How do I retrieve the mean taken from each of the 99 levels, for all 6 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `np.mean(array,axis=1)` to get means within the array.

I'm not sure I understand the dimensionality of the data, but I think you are trying to maintain the top 99 categories and take the mean of the 99 x 6 observations within.

if your array is named array, this will get you 99 results of each mean:

```
np.mean(np.mean(np.mean(array, axis=1), axis=1), axis=1)
```

If your data is stored the opposite way, with you wanting to keep the innermost 99 categories, then change the 1s to 0s in the axis variable.

If you just want the mean over everything np.mean(array) will give you the mean of means.

Comment: That's very close to what I'm looking for. I want the mean for each section of numbers, so for example, there's a section of numbers where the height is around 34, because each section has a mean of 1, then 34 ft, then 68 ft, then 3900 ft, and then 4000 ft. I wanted to get the mean of each of those sections of numbers, if that makes sense.

Comment: hmmm not sure I understand how your results are stored. Could you post a sample matrix and what your desired results are?

Comment: Hmmm Are you looking for means at 1 level deeper? Is so, just lop of one of the nested np.mean to get `np.mean(np.mean(array, axis=1), axis=1)`

Comment: I was looking for one level deeper that actually did it thank you so much! I do have one more question now-how do I graph the mean of the data from np.mean(np.mean(array, axis=0), axis=1) into a pcolormesh to plot a constant height slice?

Comment: @KingAndy No need to call mean twice: `np.mean(array, axis=(0,2))`.

Comment: Cool thank you. How do I take the mean then of each set of numbers and plot them?

Comment: if it's just a list of means `import matplotlib
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(means)`